# Using foreach instead of nested for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel.foreach

My objective is to use `foreach` instead of the conventional nested for loop to save running time. Let's consider the following case.

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(3,4)
c <- c(1,2)

myfunc <- function(a, b, c) {
       x1 <- a*rnorm(5,0,1)
       x2 <- b*rnorm(5,0,1)
       x3 <- c*rnorm(5,0,1)
       xxx <- cbind(x1,x2,x3)
       return(as.data.frame(xxx))
}
```

Using the conventional `for loop`, I can simulate data for all combinations (`a*b*c`).

```
# Using for loop.

df1 <- NULL
for(i in a) {
  for(j in b) {
    for (k in c) {
      df1 <- rbind(df1, myfunc(i,j,k))
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make this using `foreach` loop? I tried the following. But I'm not sure whether my code generates the intended data. Thanks!

```
# Using foreach loop.

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(7) 
registerDoParallel(cl)

df2 <- foreach(i = a, .combine = 'rbind') %:%
        foreach(j = b, .combine = 'rbind') %:%
        foreach(k = c, .combine = 'rbind') %dopar% {
        xx <- myfunc(i,j,k)
        return(xx)
      }
df2
```

Comment: Are you particularly interested in `foreach` or also `parLapply` etc. syntax? The issue is that you previous code is inefficient and not very suitable for parallelization since each nested loop depends on the other. This is similarly why passing foreach() to another foreach() is not going to work well in most cases and apply() or map reduce style approaches will be simpler and faster. Having many nested foreach loops won't produce much benefit from parallelization. Looking like an XY problem https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Thanks. As I planned to simulate a million datasets with a large sample size, I'm particularly interested in `foreach`.

Comment: `foreach` is one of the slower implementations of parallelization, with parLapply outperforming it significantly in many applications, so I would advise against using it. If you indeed have *large* sample sizes and a million data sets, you will also not be able to store the object in memory, so you will need to use a database. Some functions will be much faster working with databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the nested loops entirely by using `CJ()` from the `data.table` package, as shown below. If you alternatively prefer not to use packages, `grid.expand()` is a much slower base R version. Just call `expand.grid(x,y,z)`.

```r
library(data.table)

# Example vectors
x <- c(1, 2)
y <- c(3, 4)
z <- c(1, 2)

# Make a single object
dt <- CJ(x,y,z)

dt
#>    x y z
#> 1: 1 3 1
#> 2: 1 3 2
#> 3: 1 4 1
#> 4: 1 4 2
#> 5: 2 3 1
#> 6: 2 3 2
#> 7: 2 4 1
#> 8: 2 4 2
```

This is incredibly fast and uses built-in parallelization, although you can further speed things up by splitting all of the vectors into multiple, equal-length vectors and treating them as grouping factors within which parallel processing can occur. This is basically manual "chunking."

Once you have this object, you could use `foreach()` to parallelize your code many different ways. For example, you could split up `dt` into a list of smaller `dt` by row or by column. With the rows, you would just generate a `data.frame` per group of rows and `bind_rows()` or `rbind()` depending upon your approach. Alternatively, you can operate on each column in parallel and bind them together instead.

Here's an example going row-by-row with `foreach()` to produce your output. I didn't set up a cluster so it says it is in serial for now:

```r
library(foreach)
set.seed(123)

# For each row in dt, multiply each of the 3 columns by 5 random values from
# N(0,1) and return the 5 rows and 3 columns
output <- foreach(x = iterators::iter(dt, by = "row")) %dopar%
  data.table(
    x = x$x * rnorm(5),
    y = x$y * rnorm(5),
    z = x$z * rnorm(5)
  )
#> Warning: executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered

head(rbindlist(output), 10)
#>               x          y          z
#>  1: -0.56047565  5.1451950  1.2240818
#>  2: -0.23017749  1.3827486  0.3598138
#>  3:  1.55870831 -3.7951837  0.4007715
#>  4:  0.07050839 -2.0605586  0.1106827
#>  5:  0.12928774 -1.3369859 -0.5558411
#>  6:  1.78691314 -3.2034711 -3.3733866
#>  7:  0.49785048 -0.6539247  1.6755741
#>  8: -1.96661716 -3.0780133  0.3067462
#>  9:  0.70135590 -2.1866737 -2.2762739
#> 10: -0.47279141 -1.8751178  2.5076298
```